# Use materialize with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, materialize

Anyone know how I can use materializecss.com with Angular and UI-Router?
To add content inside the ui-view stops working materialize (parallax, grid system, etc.)

```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/libs/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/libs/materialize.min.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/libs/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/libs/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/libs/ngStorage.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>



 var app = angular.module('elementif', [
   'ngStorage',
   'ngRoute',
   'ui.router'
  ]);

  app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {    
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
        $stateProvider
            .state("home", {
                url: "/home",
                templateUrl: "pages/home.html",
                controller: 'sesionController'
            })
            .state("myProfile", {
                url: "/myProfile",
                templateUrl: "pages/myProfile.html",
                controller: 'sesionController'
            });

   }
]);
```

Comment: setup this https://github.com/krescruz/angular-materialize

Comment: After load page run this componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try angular-materialize.

https://github.com/krescruz/angular-materialize